# How to place UIStepper vertically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uistepper

I am developing a products storage app and need to implement a UIStepper in it. The problem is that I just can't place it vertically as I would like to have it.

So does anyone know a way I can do this??

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to modify the transform:

```
stepper.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0);
```

Edit:

I now see that this is problematic for IB. I often create my views programmatically and this does not seem to be an issue:

```
UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150, 150, 27, 94)];

// this doesn't even have a problem:
UIStepper *stepper = [[UIStepper alloc] init];
```

It only seems to be an issue with IB. Setting the frame after the fact also does not seem to help.

Comment: Well, it's rotated but a part of the stepper is now missing, not visual, like it was clipped.

Comment: When you say, "not visual", does that mean you can correctly see it vertically, but it won't allow you to click on a certain area because it might have been clipped?

Comment: @MarcoAlmeida updated my answer, I will try to find a solution for IB.

Comment: @Firo Yes the problem is just like you pointed out. I used your code and now I got it displaying it correctly, but there's a new problem. The clicking area of each button is not correct. Depending on where I click on the '-' the '+'is the one that actually clicks.